# PHP Multidimensional Array Access

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key-value

Say I have a multidimensional array in PHP such as:

```
this_array= array(
    string_name=>'string', 
    string_array=>array(
        'string_key'=>'string_val'
    )
)
```

How am I to access string_array's key-val pairs? Is it just:

```
this_array['string_array']['string_key']
```

Or is it something different?

Comment: Yes, you can access string_val with `$arr['string_array']['string_key']`. And you could try it before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code should look something like this, if you were intending on using strings as your keys.

```
$this_array= array(
     'string_name' => 'string', 
    'string_array' => array(
        'string_key' => 'string_val'
    )
);
```

Yes, you will access it by:

```
$this_array['string_array']['string_key'];
```