# Getting Session id in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to cakephp this is what i did to get my session id :

```
   $mySessionVars = $this->Session->read('Auth');
   debug( $mySessionVars );
```

and after debugging I got this

```
 array(
'User' => array(
    'id' => '3',
    'full_name' => 'Saurav M',
    'email' => 'samual@gmail.com',
    'group_id' => '1',
    'created' => '2013-02-16 08:04:30',
    'modified' => '2013-02-16 08:04:30',
    'Group' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Master Admin',
        'created' => '2012-11-13 04:16:40',
        'modified' => '2012-11-13 04:16:40'
    )
)
 )
```

I  want to get the user id ,will any one please help me out

Comment: Just to be sure; are you looking for the **User-id** or the **session id**? If you're looking for the User-id, please change the title of your question to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In Cake you can access Session variables like this (known as dot notation).

```
  $all_auth_data = $this->Session->read('Auth');  
  $user_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');   
  $user_group_array = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.Group');     
  $user_group_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.Group.id');
```

Will return the data indicated by the variable name. But you should really [read up on the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707272/php-multidimensional-array-access) linked in the comment, as it's quite basic php.

Comment: thanks a lot I have used this to get the user_id                                                        $user_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');

Comment: If you want to get the user ID the most portable way is `AuthComponent::user('id');`